# Soap Request With Postman

Tags: api, soap, soapui, postman

I cant figure out on how to make a SoapUI call in postman to [swea riksbank](https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/docs/api/index.htm)
 (Swedish bank). I have the [wsdl](https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/wsdl/sweaWS.wsdl) url in the request url and can get [this](https://pastebin.com/CyjrS6Ab) as result when I leave the request body empty. But when I try to enter a request example from the api documentation I still get the same response as above

```
//the request example
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"xmlns:xsd="http://swea.riksbank.se/xsd">
<soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <xsd:getAnnualAverageExchangeRates>
            <year>2010</year>
            <month>4</month>
            <languageid>en</languageid>
        </xsd:getAnnualAverageExchangeRates>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have also tried this [link](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/08/22/making-soap-requests-using-postman/) but cant get it to work at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of the WSDL you linked it have:

```
<soap12:address location="http://swea.riksbank.se:80/sweaWS/services/SweaWebServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint"/>
```

If you set `http://swea.riksbank.se:80/sweaWS/services/SweaWebServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint` as the URL, use POST as the method, set raw as the body type and select XML in the drop-down.

Your body is correct except it is missing a space before `xmlns:xsd="http://swea.riksbank.se/xsd"`

Comment: Thanks a lot! have been stuck with this for a while now